# Magento 2 Admin Grid Filter lost on reload

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter

I created a custom grid with custom entities in the admin section. Everything works as expected, even the filter. 
If I add a filter and reload the filter, the filter is lost though. This doesn't happen in the product grid, what am I missing? How to keep the filter even after reload the grid?

This is the specific part of my ui_component for the grid:

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">lot_record_lot_list.lot_record_lot_list.raffiniert_datasheet_lot_columns</item>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">lot_record_lot_list.lot_record_lot_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
            </item>
            <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">lot_record_lot_list.lot_record_lot_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">lot_record_lot_list.lot_record_lot_list.raffiniert_datasheet_lot_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filters>
```

Is there anything else I need to add to keep the filter after reloading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add below code to your **`listingToolbar`** section.

```
<bookmark name="bookmarks">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">lot_record_lot_list</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</bookmark>
```

As you required a feature which is called **bookmark** in the grid so that the filter will save in **`ui_bookmark`** table and keep the filter even after reload the grid.

Please let me know in case you need further assistance.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you, you've saved me a lot of time!

Comment: :) sounds great... upvoted

Comment: Perfect answer!